# Como criar um Bubble Plot

Tags: r, gráfico

Alguém com experiência na formulação desse gráfico? Estou com muita dúvida, principalmente no diâmetro dos círculos e na colocação da variável do eixo X.
Sou doutorando da UFPE e muitos estatísticos que procurei não sabiam formular o gráfico em questão. Eu sempre trabalhei com o SPSS e tem sido um desafio enveredar no R.

No meu caso, segue o exemplo:

No eixo Y: Os níveis de incapacidade funcional.

Valores:

1. Incapacidade Mínima (0 a 20%),
2. Incapacidade Moderada (21 a 40%),
3. Incapacidade Severa (41 a 60%),
4. Invalidez (61 a 80%),
5. Restrita ao Leito (81 a 100%).

No eixo X: Localização e envolvimento das articulações pélvicas.

Valores:

1. Síndrome da Cintura Pélvica,
2. Sinfisiólise,
3. Síndrome Sacroilíaca Unilateral,
4. Síndrome Sacroilíaca Bilateral,
5. Miscelânea.

** Os Círculos representam a intensidade da dor (quanto maior o square, maior a intensidade de dor). Essa variável vai de 0 até 100mm (Variável contínua).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: no ggplot2 não é difícil fazer, mas é necessário fornecer um conjuntinho de dados de exemplo para responder com código funcional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O jeito mais fácil de se fazer isso no R é utilizando a função `symbols`. Como você não forneceu dados específicos, criei alguns aleatórios, utilizando o argumento `prob` para causar uma destribuição desigual.

```
n <- 50
set.seed(0)
y <- sample(c(1:10), n, replace = TRUE, prob = 10:1)
x <- sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5)
r <- sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE)
```

Para usar a função, basta definir os parâmetros com as posições `x` e `y` de cada polígono, e no caso de círculos, utilizar o argumento `circle` com o raio dos círculos:

```
symbols(x, y, circles = r)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta função funciona como a maioria das funções gráficas do R. Você pode definir `main`, `xlab`, `cex`, etc. Também pode adicionar outros elementos, utilizando por exemplo `abline`.

Uma característica especial é que, independente da relação altura/largura, serão plotados círculos. Um destaque especial deve ser dado para a seguinte parte da ajuda da função:

> Argument inches controls the sizes of the symbols. If TRUE (the default), the symbols are scaled so that the largest dimension of any symbol is one inch.

Ou seja, mesmo se você mudar `r`, o maior sempre terá um tamanho final fixo, o que dificilmente agrada. Podemos usar `inches = FALSE` e controlar os raios (que agora estarão na mesma escala do eixo x):

```
symbols(x, y, circles = r/300, inches = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro detalhe importante: A função cria os círculos a partir do valor do **raio**, mas normalmente queremos as bolhas com **área** proporcional à medida. Nesse caso seria importante fazer a transformação. Precisamos apenas reorganizar a fórmula da área do círculo (`A = π * r²`):

```
area <- sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE)
r <- sqrt(area / pi)
```

Em alguns casos a função `symbols` pode ser limitante, e a utilização de `polygon()` com uma trigonometria básica pode ser mais adequada, contanto que você também controle as proporções de forma correta. Outra possibilidade é utilizar o pacote `ggplot2` que certamente dá conta do recado.

Comment: Molx, agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda. O meu estudo contém aproximadamente 90 pessoas e os círculos ficam totalmente fora dos padrões. Como proceder? Caso prefiras posso enviar os dados...

Comment: Você tentou usar `inches = FALSE` e modificar os valores de `r` para procurar uma normalização que te agrade? Você pode também postar os dados na pergunta original, com seu resultado obtido, e explicar o que não ficou como você gostaria (ou criar outra pergunta). Podemos procurar uma maneira de fazer utilizando ggplot2 também, que vai facilitar especialmente caso você queria uma legenda com o tamanho dos círculos.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade Veja o comentário acima. Fiz também uma edição para lembrar que a função funciona com base no raio, você talvez queria transformar para área.

Comment: Vou tentar seguir suas explanações e te dou um retorno. Muito obrigado pela atenção e disponibilidade! Abraço

Answer (score 3):

Olha, o ideal é fornecer junto com a pergunta pelo menos algum conjunto de dados de exemplo.

Mas vou te fornecer um exemplo aqui, parecido com o seu, utilizando o ggplot2:

```
## Dados de exemplo
dados = data.frame(x = sort(rep(seq(from = 1960, to = 2010, by = 5), 3)),
                   y = rep(1:3, 33),
                   raio = rnorm(33, mean = 2, sd = 3),
                   categoria = sample(x = 1:10, size = 33, replace = T))

## Colocando o tamanho das bolas pela categoria
g = ggplot(data = dados, aes(y = y, x = x, size = categoria)) + geom_point()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
## Colocando o tamanho das bolas pelo raio (variável numérica)
g = ggplot(data = dados, aes(y = y, x = x, size = categoria, colour=raio)) + geom_point()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que no ggplot2 você pode mapear características dos dados, como valores para o eixo x, eixo y, cor, tamanho e forma, dentro da função aes(). Assim, para conseguir que as "bolhas" tenham tamanho dependendo de uma variável é só colocar o size =  variavel_da_bolha.

Você deve conseguir customizar esse código para os seus propósitos.